# Testing for media queries in yepnope.js - false positive or...?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, modernizr, yepnope, browser-feature-detection

I am using this code to test for media query support as I want to load a polyfill for e.g. IE8.

```
yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.mq('(only all)'),
    nope : ['scripts/respond.js']
});
```

It works (= respond.js gets loaded in oder IE), but now I've just discovered that respond.js also gets loaded in Safari.

After having read [the docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) I believe that respond.js is loaded because there are some kind of media queries Safari *doesn't* support. Is this true? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that Safari doesn't support certain media queries, but that `(only all)` is not a valid media query. There should be no parentheses around the `only` keyword or the media type `all`:

```
yepnope({
    test : Modernizr.mq('only all'),
    nope : ['scripts/respond.js']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using modernizr as well but found the easiest way add media query support for IE7 and IE8  was simply to use something like this in the page head

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure you are calling respond.js after the CSS files have loaded.

This is working well for me.

Good luck!